# Fetch and format data into arrays of objects? Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to return data in an array of objects...
I've done this before with JS, but it was a mess, was looking for a cleaner approach and slowly learning TS but i seem to have hit a wall...

```
export {};
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const fetch = require("isomorphic-fetch");

interface PlayerStats {
  name: string;
  role: string;
  score: string;
  matches: string;
  totalBattles: number;
}

const fetchData = async (faction: string) => {
  const req = await fetch("https://localhost/3000/" + faction);
  const data: string = await req.text();
  const $ = cheerio.load(data);

  const SquadElements: Element[] = $("#teamDetails > div.memberList").toArray();

  const playerStats: PlayerStats[] = SquadElements.map((el: Element) => {
    const name: string = $(el).find(".member .name p").text() || "";
    const score: string = $(el).find(".member .stats .battlesWon").text();
    const matches: string = $(el).find(".member .stats .matchesPlayed").text();
    const role: string = $(el).find(".member .specialty h6").text();
    const totalBattles: number = parseInt(matches) * 3;

    return { name, score, matches, role, totalBattles };
  });

  console.log(playerStats[0]);
  return playerStats;
};
fetchData("9a7059e278");
```

`console.log(playerStats[0]);` returns `name: 'name1name2name3name4name5'.. etc`

Comment: Just guessing, but try moving `.member` from `$(el).find()` up here `$("#teamDetails > div.memberList .member").toArray();`

Comment: It worked!! I am so happy and so annoyed at the same time haha, this was the fix, can't believe i didn't catch it... Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Thomas for the help... It was as simple as:

`$("#teamDetails > div.memberList > .member").toArray();`

instead of:

`$("#teamDetails > div.memberList").toArray();`